# Tensors: coordinates and index notation

Tags: tensors

Many textbooks on tensors start with a sentence like "An equation written in tensor form is valid in any coordinate system." The second sentence is often "Closely associated with tensor calculus is the index notation." According to me, this seems contradictory. The first sentence seems to state that coordinate systems should be avoided while the second one emphasizes the need of a coordinate system. How far can we go in tensor (calculus) without relying on index notation? Are there books specifically following this approach?

Comment: Well yes but the idea is that you sum over an orthonormal basis for the tangent/cotangent space as appropriate. The fact that the choice of basis doesn't matter is nontrivial, depending on how you define the tensor. Mathematicians often prefer to avoid indices, compared to physicists. It's analogous to how one can define tensor products and exterior products naturally using universal properties with out mentioning bases. In practice, you often pick a basis so you can actually write elements down.

Comment: A tensor is like a vector in an abstract vector space. It has no components and indices. But if you choose a basis of a vector space, then the vector can be written in terms of the basis, components and indices. A similar thing happens with tensors.

Comment: yes thanks. I am not questioning the correctness and appropriateness of the two topics (1) coordinate system invariance and (2) index notation but rather their articulation in many textbooks. Many authors, probably more in physics than in mathematics, jump from the universal aspects of the first topic to the specific aspects of the second one without a clear explanation. At least, this is what I have commonly observed but there are plenty of textbooks that I have yet to read.

Comment: Yes. Traditionally, both mathematicians and physicists used indices. But physicists knew that physical laws should not depend on units or coordinates. mathematicians knew that geometric properties of a space or surface should not depend on coordinates. So both knew that whatever they computed had physical or geometric significance only if it was invariant or at least behaved in a nice way if the coordinates changed. This is all at least implicit in old books. But too many books just dive into the calculations without pointing this out.

Comment: Is your concern, more specifically, "how to determine if an expression written in Einstein notation is actually invariant of the choice of basis"? Because that is definitely worth thinking about. Ultimately it is analogous to the way a linear map $f\colon \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is equivalent to the data of an $(m\times n)$-matrix $A$ in a specified basis. (Except its a a smooth choice of maps, and the maps are multilinear, etc.)

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but Connor & Floyd's book "The Relation of Cobordism to $K$-Theories" contains a lot of remarkably index-free linear algebra which is relevant to physics (quaternionic bundles, complex bundles, Hodge star, etc).

Comment: yes because as pointed out by @Dean, "A tensor is like a vector in an abstract vector space. It has no components and indices." but then, suddenly, they have indices!? And the question of the basis invariance seems to be pushed away. I forgot to mention that many authors do not even bother mentioning that the identities they are showing are actually correct only in certain coordinate systems. For instance, it is fairly common to read that "in index notation, the divergence of a vector field is $\partial _i f_i$". I'll try to get a copy of the book.

Comment: As for how far you can go without indices, you can go *very* far. If you look at almost any modern differential geometry textbook (Lee, Tu, Petersen, Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine, etc.), you'll see that they clearly want to avoid coordinates, bases, and therefore indices. However, you can't avoid them completely, and, sometimes, even if you can, the calculation can be easier with coordinates. In fact, I always recommend that you become fluent with doing calculations an proofs using either approach.